# Деплой приложения на node js, настройка сервера

Tags: node.js, nginx, express

У меня есть приложение node js на основе express. Интересует как правильно разворачивать его на продакшене. С php я использовал nginx и там же прописывал hostname. Но у ноды есть express который тоже является сервером, должен ли я использовать nginx в данной ситуации или нет? Если нет, то где прописывать хост? Не помешал бы пример конфига. Совсем недавно с нодой)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал с помощью nginx проксировать. И статику им же отдавать.

1. Запускаем express на 3000 порту.
2. Проксируем запросы к нему через nginx.

Как-то так:

```
# express сервак на 3000 порту
upstream nodejs {
    server localhost:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/nodejs;

    # статику самим nginx'ом отдаём
    location ~ ^/(images/|img/|javascript/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|media/|static/|robots.txt|favicon.ico) {
         #в /var/www/nodejs/public весь статик контент держим
         root /var/www/nodejs/public;
         access_log off;
         expires max;
    }

    # проксируем запросы на 3000 порт
    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://nodejs;
        proxy_set_header Host $host ; 
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо. Для общего развития хотелось бы знать какие ещё есть альтернативы кроме проксирования через сторонний сервер, как средствами express всё сделать?

Comment: @abakan что именно? express можно запустить и открыть порт наружу, но это будет небезопасно, медленнее. Плюс проблемы с масштабированием, т.к. nodejs однопоточен. В случае с nginx вы можете запустить несколько серверов express на разных портах и раунд робином проксировать к ним запросы через nginx.